# Rails not loading files in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

When I'm switching to production on localhost, Rails does not load files that are loaded in development.

So, when I use development, this files are loaded:

```
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.alerts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.clearing.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.cookie.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.dropdown.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.forms.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.joyride.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.magellan.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.orbit.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.reveal.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.section.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.tooltips.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.topbar.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.interchange.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.placeholder.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/foundation.abide.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/foundation/index.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/top_feed.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I use production, files are not loading, scss is not interpreted, only pure css lines and I get the error that

> Sprockets::FileNotFound in Home#index - couldn't find file 'foundation'
>   Is this a precompile error? If somebody can point me in the right direction.

In production.rb: `config.serve_static_assets = true`

If I add `config.assets.precompile =  ['*.js', '*.css', '*.css.erb']` it's not doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either have to require the `foundation` folder in your application.js, if it's being loaded on every page

```
# application.js
...
//= require_tree foundation
```

or create a new manifest file for js and add that to precompilation.

```
# foundation.js
//= require_tree foundation

# config/environments/production.rb
config.assets.precompile += %w(foundation.js)

# in your view or main layout
= javascript_include_tag "foundation"
```

Comment: yes, I had to add _tree in application.js Thanks a lot, I was looking for hours..